# DetailView template is not showing value of selected record. in django

Tags: python, django

On DetailView template I am not able to print name,date of post  only '|' sign is being printed but on ListView it is working fine. Here is code written in files. Thanks!!

> **blog/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset =
Blog.objects.all(), template_name ='blog.html')),

url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=Blog, template_name='detail.html')), )
```

**blog.html**

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}
     {%  for post in object_list %}
        <ul> <a href="/blog/{{ post.id }}">{{ post.name }} </a>||{{ post.date }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}

 {% endblock %}
```

**detial.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} <h2> <a href="/blog/{{ post.id }}">{{ post.name }}
 </a>||{{ post.date }}</h2> {% endblock %}
```

Comment: By default the `context` of DetailView is `object` and not `post`. You need to either change the context to `object.name`

Comment: OR set `context_object_name="post"` in DetailView

Answer (score 2):

context_object_name Designates the name of the variable to use in the context. Default is "object"

Try

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} <h2> <a href="/blog/{{ object.id }}">{{ object.name }}
 </a>||{{ object.date }}</h2> {% endblock %}
```

See [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#singleobjectmixin) and [making-friendly-template-contexts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#making-friendly-template-contexts)

Comment: thanks buddy!! The concept of 'context_object_name' was never in my mind. btw how this guy in tutorial managed to print with 'post'. He has not set 'context_object_name="post"' anywhere in tutorial.Check at 20:00 his template for DetailView.

Comment: Very good point. "object" is default but you may also have available "blog"/lovercase(NameOfTheModel) try {{ blog.id }}

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!! in above comment link was missing. here is the link for tutorial which I wanted to point out.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srHZoj3ASmk